# Compare Validator validates only one yii2

Tags: validation, yii2, yii2-advanced-app

I am using **compareValidator** in **yii2** form.

Here is the code

`[['passwordConfirm'], 'compare', 'compareAttribute' => 'password'],`

It should work fine because its the code in the documentation as well

But what happens is it only validates the **password** once.

For example if I input **password** and **Confirm Password** once it will validate fine but if I go back to the **password** field and change the password than it doesn't compare **confirm password** input with new **password** input

Anybody else having the same problem???
or I did something wrong here as well

Here is the `model` code

```
 public function rules()
{
    return [
        ['username', 'filter', 'filter' => 'trim'],
        ['username', 'required'],  
        ['username', 'unique', 'targetClass' => '\common\models\User', 'message' => 'This username has already been taken.'],
        ['username', 'string', 'min' => 2, 'max' => 255],

        ['email', 'filter', 'filter' => 'trim'],
        ['email', 'required'],
        ['email', 'email'],
        ['email', 'string', 'max' => 255],
        ['email', 'unique', 'targetClass' => '\common\models\User', 'message' => 'This email address has already been taken.'],

        ['password', 'required'],
        ['password', 'string', 'min' => 6],

        [['passwordConfirm'], 'compare', 'compareAttribute' => 'password'],

    ];
}

public function attributeLabels()
{
    return [
        'passwordConfirm' => 'Confirm Password',
        'username' => 'Username',
        'email' => 'Email',
    ];
}
```

And here is the `view` code

```
    <?php $form = ActiveForm::begin(['options'=>['enctype'=>'multipart/form-data']]); ?>

        <?= $form->field($model, 'username')->textInput( ['data-toggle' => 'tooltip',
            'data-placement' =>
                'right',
            'title' => 'Username should contain at least 6 characters'
        ]) ?>

        <?= $form->field($model, 'password')->passwordInput(['data-toggle' => 'tooltip',
            'data-placement' =>
                'right',
            'title' => 'Password should contain at least 6 characters',

        ]) ?>

        <?= $form->field($model, 'passwordConfirm')->passwordInput() ?>

        <?= $form->field($model, 'email') ?>

    <?php ActiveForm::end(); ?>
```

Thank you

Comment: can you post your model, form and controller's action code?

Comment: I'm having the same problem. and that's why I want to try a custom validation but it's not working on the front end. I did try using `when` validation together with `compare` but nothing works.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is the expected behavior. The validator is attached to the `passwordConfirm` attribute and therefore is triggered when that attribute is changed. Specific action depends on how `validateOnChange`, `validateOnBlur`, and `validateOnType` properties of `ActiveField` are set.

However, the whole form should get revalidated before it is submitted, so you will see an error if you went back and changed the `password` field.

If you absolutely need to enable validation in the scenario you describe, you can either add another `compare` validator to `password` attribute in backend, or add a call to validate `passwordCompare` attribute when your `password` field changes in frontend.

I suggest you stick to the original implementation though, because the form will get validated eventually, if not on frontend, then on backend.